# React Redux Actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using react with redux and it gives errors when I declare the actions..The source code is below..

src/actions/index.js

```
const addTask =(task)=>{
    return {
        type:'ADD_TASK',
        payload:task
    };
},
deleteTask=(taskId)=>{
    return {
        type:'DELETE_TASK',
        payload:taskId
    };
};

export default {addTask, deleteTask};
```

And the error that it gives is

Failed to compile
./src/components/taskbar/index.js
Attempted import error: 'addTask' is not exported from '../../actions/index'.

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be more about how you import the action in another file.

Comment: because its a export default, you need to import it like this:
`import actions from '../path'`
and not like this: 
`import {actions} from '../path`

Comment: Also you're missing `const` for `deleteTask` declaration.

Comment: ... `import taskAction from '../../actions/index'` Then you can do `taskAction.addTask()`

Comment: @Clarity Not the best way to do this, but there is a comma after the addTask declaration, so deleteTask is assigned to a const

Comment: @giuseppedeponte right, didn't notice the comma.

Comment: I'm importing actions to src/components/taskbar/index.js  as import {addTask} from '../../actions/index';       and there's a button click as <button onClick={()=>this.props.addTask(this.refs.task.value)}>Add task</button>

Answer (score 0):

You can use **named** exports/imports :

```
// Named export
export const addTask =(task)=>{
    return {
        type:'ADD_TASK',
        payload:task
    };
}
```

```
// named import
import { addTask } from '../../actions/index'
```

or **default** export/import:

```
const addTask =(task)=>{
    return {
        type:'ADD_TASK',
        payload:task
    };
}
// default export
export default { addTask }
```

```
// default import
import taskActions from '../../actions/index'
const addTask = taskActions.addTask
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this

```
export const addTask =(task)=>{
    return {
        type:'ADD_TASK',
        payload:task
    };
}

export const deleteTask=(taskId)=>{
    return {
        type:'DELETE_TASK',
        payload:taskId
    };
};
```

Comment: mapStateToProps() in Connect(Taskbar) must return a plain object. Instead received undefined.